# GenericRepository pattern no error on line by line execution but throw The ObjectContext instance has been disposed in normal mode on inserting data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

This code when calling from the controller to save data working fine only when code executes line by line in debug mode otherwise data is not saving in DB and sometimes throw an exception on the save method as he ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

## Controller

```
 ...
 await Task.Run(() =>
  {
     var result = WorkUnit.CategoriesRepository.Insert(model);
  });
```

## GenericRepsitory.cs

```
public async Task<int> Insert(TModel model)
    {
        var entity = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(model);
        _DbSet.Add(entity);
        return await Save();
    }
    public async Task<int> Save()
    {
        try
        {                     
             return   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                                            
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Task.Run() from controller and call with await only done the job. it's working fine now.